# javascript::The toggle function cannot work

Tags: javascript, toggle

I get a problem when creating a dropdown list. When I trigger the dropdown by toggle the "show-item" class, it doesn't work. Can you guys help me to see what happen? Thx!!! There's the code below

```
var duration_dropdown = document.getElementById('duration-dropdown');
var mins_ctn = document.getElementById('mins-ctn');

duration_dropdown.onclick = function(){
  mins_ctn.classList.toggle('show-item')
}

    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Dropdown Demo</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-ctn">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button id="duration-dropdown" class="dropdown-mins">MM</button>
                <div class="mins-ctn" id="mins-ctn">
                    <span class="minute">01</span>
                    <span class="minute">02</span>
                    <span class="minute">03</span>
                    <span class="minute">04</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="dropdown.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: what is the `show-item` class?

Comment: Add `.show-item { display: none; }` to see your code at work. There's nothing else wrong with it that I can see

Comment: Kindly provide reproducible code in which we can see the error. The code provided as of now has no error. Just add CSS for the classes e.g. `.mins-ctn { visibility: hidden; }` and `.show-item { visibility: visible; }`.

Comment: There's no error message shown on console.

Comment: 'show-item' is ''display:block'.

Comment: @Lctrayden that doesn't help. The element is already display block by default. Add `display: none;` to `.mins-ctn`